# How to disable accessibility focus of an element while its isAccessibilityElement = false

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uiaccessibility

I turned the UITableViewCell's accessibility off in different ways. However, it is still focusable when selected.

```
override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    selectionStyle = .none
}

convenience init() {
    self.init()

    isAccessibilityElement = false
}

public override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()

    isAccessibilityElement = false
    isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    subView.isAccessibilityElement = false
}

public override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
    return false
}
```

This is a screenshot from the view debugger:

[image]

Any clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making `accessibilityElementsHidden = true` solved it.

```
public override func didMoveToWindow() {
    super.didMoveToWindow()

    isAccessibilityElement = false
    accessibilityElementsHidden = true
}
```